# How can I use cypress to assert that an image is the correct one?

Tags: javascript, image, href, cypress

I'm trying to test a case where a user can insert a URL for their profile and want to make sure that the right image is loaded up. Is there a way where I can assert that the picture's src is the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are talking about this feature check it out [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Preferences) as an example

```
cy.visit(URL);
cy.get('your_selector').should('have.attr', 'src', '/your_picture_src')
```